# update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_312/bin/java for java not registered; not setting

Tags: java, linux, java-8

I am trying to install `Java Developer Kit 8` by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
echo 'Updating eventually the correct version of Java...'
var=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' 'NR==1 {print $2}') # get the actual version 
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk${var}/bin/java
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
default: Updating eventually the correct version of Java...
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_312/bin/java for java not registered; not setting
```

Is there a missing step in the commands?

Answer (score 3):

I'm somewhat confused. You're directly invoking the java command, which will use the java that's already redirected in in the alternatives configuration.  You are literally attempting to set the default java to the java that you've just installed? If you don't change anything, then it should already be pointing to this instance of java.

Secondly, you're assuming that the path to java is the one you're specifying there. It doesn't have to be the case. When I create a minimal docker container with openjdk-8-jdk (and dpkg, so update-alternatives is available), then the path to java is:

```
root@c330511a7cde:/# update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

So the path that you *should* have been using was this path.

Now I've manually installed a few more java versions, and because of priorities, java-17 is now the default java, so the output is a bit longer:

```
root@c330511a7cde:/# update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

In this case, you're probably better *finding* the java-8 path from update-alternatives and setting it that way, so something like:

```
java_8_path=$(update-alternatives --list java | grep 'java-8-openjdk' | head -1)
if [ -n "$java_8_path" ]; then
    sudo update-alternatives --set java "$java_8_path" || echo "darn"
else
    echo "could not find java8 in alternatives list" 1>&2
fi
```